# Using resources inside a jar from war module

Tags: java, jar

I'm having a jar file say toolkit.jar which contains resource files under com.project.resources. When I tested independently I can read those resources with  `Class.getResource`. But when I used the jar file in war module (web service), getResource always returns null. How can I access those resource file?

```
com/project/resources/ contains arial.ttf
com/project/toolkit/ contains ToolKit.java
```

renderer is ITextRenderer object.

```
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont(this.getClass().getResource("../resources/arial.ttf").
    toString(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

And this toolkit.jar is using in a web service.

Comment: is it still in classpath ?

Comment: A previous post should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/java-reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar .... if it does not work use ClassLoader instance to getResource

Comment: Do you use an application server?

Comment: @Jens Yes, Apache Tomcat 7.0 and 8.0

Comment: Show us the actual code using getResource(), and tell us precisely what is null.

Comment: @AurA ClassLoader gives the tomcat bin path which is not what I really need.

Answer (score -1):

Use getResourceAsStream() instead of getResource

```
InputStream in =
new InputStreamReader(FileLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt") );
```

If its doesn't work

The best way to look to a config file from a webapp is to implement the servlet method init().
Let’ try using the same code

```
InputStream in =
new InputStreamReader(FileLoaderServlet.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt") );
```

Refer
https://haveacafe.wordpress.com/2008/10/19/how-to-read-a-file-from-jar-and-war-files-java-and-webapp-archive/

Comment: Can you please clarify the `FileLoader`?

Comment: FileLoader is just a class name - its a filename you want to access

Comment: Then it's same as what I did.

Comment: have you refereed this link https://haveacafe.wordpress.com/2008/10/19/how-to-read-a-file-from-jar-and-war-files-java-and-webapp-archive/

Comment: Yes, I did. Nothing +ve

Comment: have you used getResourceAsStream() instead of getResource

Comment: class.getClassLoader() always starts from lib directory of apache tomcat. So this will search files in the same path

Comment: InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt"));
BufferredReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));